# error "Couldn't find User without an ID" when trying to create a tweet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm trying to make a twitter clone where a tweet displays the username of the user next to it. however getting the above error message and highlighting the first line of my create method. any ideas on how to solve.
I've done the association already.
thanks

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @tweets = Tweet.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @tweet = Tweet.new
  end

  def show
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    # @tweet = Tweet.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
    @tweet.user = @user
    if @tweet.save
      redirect_to tweets_path
    end
  end

  private

  def tweet_params
    params.require(:tweet).permit(:content, :user_id)
  end

end
```

## tweets

```
<%= simple_form_for @tweet, id: "form-submit" do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :content %>
   <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>

<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <%= tweet.content %>
      <%= tweet.user.username %>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params` hash does not contain `id`, because of that you are getting this error.

Just modify your create action as

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
    @tweet.user = current_user
    if @tweet.save
      redirect_to tweets_path
    end
  end
```

Or

instead of above you can also pass an `user_id` from the form.

```
<%= simple_form_for @tweet, id: "form-submit" do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :content %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.try(:id) %>
   <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

then modify create action as

```
  def create
    @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
    if @tweet.save
      redirect_to tweets_path
    end
  end
```

NOTE: Assuming that you are using devise gem for authentication

Comment: It could be much more appropriate if @tweet is passed in `new` action as  `@tweet = current_user.tweets.new`. All this mess up could be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Your form doesn't have `id` field, so `params[:id]` is `nil`.

Comment: sorry, so i need to add the id to the form? im quite new to this, how would i do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are defining tweet.users after using tweet_params, since for tweet_params the user is not defined, that's why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

By answer accepted here, most appropriate change could be:

```
  def new
    @tweet = current_user.tweets.new
  end

  def create
    @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
    if @tweet.save
      redirect_to tweets_path
    end
  end
```

nothing else was needed to be done.